# SWT: catch event shell to full-screen mode

Tags: java, swt, fullscreen

How can I catch set full-screen mode event? `SWT.Resize` does not catch this event.

thanks.

Comment: Do you mean maximize?

Comment: So which one is it? `shell.setFullScreen(boolean)` or `shell.setMaximized(boolean)`?

Comment: I want listen event push full screen key.

Comment: Well, there is a difference between full screen and maximize, so which one is it?

Comment: I don't know which method execute by maximize button in the title bar. I suppose shell.setMaximized(boolean).

Comment: Aha, so it's the maximize button. Now that's information we can work with. Full screen is the mode where you don't even see the title bar any more.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you're saying that `SWT.Resize` doesn't work, this works just fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");

    shell.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            if(shell.getMaximized())
                System.out.println("Maximize");
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I tried re-configure widgets if shell resize. But shell resize earlier than widgets inside it get new size. 
I detected this only now. I am sorry I was careless.

Comment: @user3378888 Does that mean that your question is answered?

Comment: Maybe yes for my first question. Thank. But I all the same don't know how I can reconfigure widgets for maximize mode. 

When I resize Window with stretch I have size of widget that it have after operation. When resize maximize sequence different.

Comment: @user3378888 I don't think I understand. Can you maybe upload a screenshot? Are you using layouts or `.setBounds()`?

Comment: I find solution. I add SWT.Resize listener for reconfigure widget. And now I have its size.